# UITableviewcells become null after the 3rd add

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an `UITableview` with custom `UITableviewCell` that has 2 Text Fields.
I have a button that adds new cells to this table. Initially i have 3 cells then I add and I add and when i add the sixth (6th) cell it crashes saying the cell is empty when i iterate over it like this:

```
NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [shtoFushaTableView numberOfSections]; ++j)
{
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [shtoFushaTableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [shtoFushaTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]);
        [cells addObject:[shtoFushaTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]]; //this is where i get an exception to add a null object
    }
}
```

The point of this iteration is to store the values of the text fields before adding a new one.
Any Idea what im doing wrong ?

Comment: Why don't you simply store the text...there is no need to store the entire cells.  This is a very bad practice that will make you run out of memory.

Comment: i store the text after this loop like this `for (ShtoFushaTableViewCell *cell in cells)
    {
        [attributeValues replaceObjectAtIndex:k withObject:cell.listingValue.text];
        k++;
    }`

Comment: I see no reason to store the cells like that...the point of a data source is to separate the cells from their data source.  In any case, it might be because that cell is currently off screen.

Comment: shouldnt this loop iterate even on those cells that are offscreen ?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  This is an odd thing to do so I've never considered it.  It depends on what you have in your cellForRowAtIndexPath I think.  The offscreen cells don't actually exist...they are created on demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably the re-use of table view cells:
When they are scrolled out of view, they are put back in a cell pool, and all data in the cells might disappear.
For this reason you should **never** store anything in a table view cell except for display.
You have to store your data in a data model, and read them from there for display in the cells.

Comment: I do have an NSMutableArray with the strings in each textfield, the problem is when adding a new cell i have to remember what textfields have been filled so they don't get empty

Comment: Now I understand why its bad practice, guess im still sleepy. Now i save the text values on my didEndEditing delegate of text fields :)